# Laravel eloquent, get 500 error with just a get()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here the code :

```
    $search = request()->get('search');
    $conciergerieSelect = request()->get('conciergerie');
    $services = Service::get();
    $available = 'Disponible';

    $prestations = Prestation::with([
        'service:name'
    ])
    ->whereHas('item', function ($query) use ($available) {
        $query->where('status', $available);
    })
    ->whereIn('conciergerie_ids', [$conciergerieSelect])
    ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
    ->get();

    $prestationsArrayIds = [];

    foreach($prestations as $prestation) {
        array_push($prestationsArrayIds, $prestation['_id']);
    }

    // dd($prestationsArrayIds); is okay i get 200 status

    $items = Item::orderBy('name')
        ->get();

     // Here if i do dd($items); it's okay i get 200 status

    return $result = [
        'items' => $items
    ];
```

The problem is that i get an 500 error if I return $result to just test $items like here.
Do you have an idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: plz post the error msg.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Tony plz check your `storage/logs/xxx.log` file, and post it.

Comment: @TsaiKoga I get no error on my logs

Comment: why do you put conciergerieSelect in side of an array ? is that already an array ? I assume it's coming from an array input

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code hope it will help you.

```
return [
    'items' => $items
];
```

Comment: For local development, you should set the APP_DEBUG environment variable to true. Then watch your error.log file to know what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
return $items->toJson();
```

if it doesn't work, try with

```
return $items->toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution :
I forget to use `->paginate(50);` instead of `->get()` because i have a pagination system in my view.
Sorry and thank you !

Comment: well.But this question is not reliable anything.it's better to remove your question.thank you